# How to z-rotate a rectangle in perspective using inskcape?

Tags: inkscape, perspective

I have managed to draw a limited perspective sketch in Inkscape. My aim is to add rectangles in perspective (like the black one already in the picture) but rotating on the z axis (xy plane) to illustrate that this figure moves along a pivot that runs along this axis.
The rotation should be from the intersection with the axis, so I’ve tried to move the rotation center and then rotate the object but it’s not producing the desired result.

Here is a PNG of my sketch:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Create something like this:

   [image]

   The black lines on the left are your axes. The cyan object on the left is a perfect rhombus that is parallel to your bottom axes. The red object on the right is a perfect square. The rectangles on the right are what I understand that you want to put into perspective with the black spot marking the intersection of the axes.
2. Apply *path → object to path* to all objects in the right half.
3. Group all objects in the right half.
4. Select the group and then the rhombus. Apply *extensions → modify path → perspective.* You should get something like this:

   [image]
5. Remove the red and cyan rhombus.
6. Align the transformed rectangles on the vertical axis using the black dot:

   [image]

Comment: The answer is perfect. The only thing I should add is that the orientation of the rectangles determine the final rotating direction so I had to try several mirror images until I got the good one.

Comment: You can reverse the path using the Path menu, IIRC. That will get the perspective right.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment on the very good answer, but I don't have enough rep.

From [this tutorial](http://www.built-to-spec.com/blog/2011/01/02/quick-inkscape-tutorial-perspective-transforms/) I found an answer to getting the correct orientation. The target shape, the one with the right perspective, needs to be a 4 sided polygon drawn clockwise from the bottom left corner.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/112052)

Comment: Your response is 100% reasonable, but I did not like any of the options I had (redundant to repeat an answer, not allowed to comment), and so I wrote my answer to make this resource more complete (as I had to google beyond the other answer).